# Document filtering by regex

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I'm trying to find best solution to verify input document. I need to check every line of the document. Basically in each line can exist invalid character or characters. The result of searching (validating) is: 'get me the index of line with invalid char and index of each invalid character in this line'.

I know how to do in standard way (open file -> read all lines -> check characters one by one), but this method isn't best optimized way. Instead of this, the best solution will be to use "MatchCollection" (in my opinion).

But how to do this correctly in C# ?

**Link:**

> http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-matches

**Example:**

> "Some Înput text here,\n Îs another lÎne of thÎs text."
>
> In first line [0] found invalid character on [6] index, in line [1]
> found invalid characters on [0, 12, 21] index.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegularExpresion
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Regex regex = null; 

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input_text = "Some Înput text here, Îs another lÎne of thÎs text.";

            string line_pattern = "\n";

            string invalid_character = "Î";

            regex = new Regex(line_pattern);

            /// Check is multiple or single line document
            if (IsMultipleLine(input_text))
            {
                /// ---> How to do this correctly for each line ? <---
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Is a single line file");

                regex = new Regex(invalid_character);

                MatchCollection mc = regex.Matches(input_text);

                Console.WriteLine($"How many matches: {mc.Count}");

                foreach (Match match in mc)
                    Console.WriteLine($"Index: {match.Index}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static bool IsMultipleLine(string input) => regex.IsMatch(input);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

- Is a single line file
- How many matches: 4
- Index: 5
- Index: 22
- Index: 34
- Index: 43

Comment: What's an *"invalid character"*? The standard way *may* be faster, post some code.

Comment: I suspect you want to match any leletter that is not ascii. Try `Regex.Matches(s, @"[\p{L}-[a-zA-Z]]")`. However, this won't contain any line index information.

Comment: Like in code, I can't find a solution for multiple line with MatchCollection use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Link:**
http://www.dotnetperls.com/regexoptions-multiline

**SOLUTION**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegularExpresion
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Regex regex = null;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input_text = @"Some Înput text here,
Îs another lÎne of thÎs text.";

            string line_pattern = "\n";

            string invalid_character = "Î";

            regex = new Regex(line_pattern);

            /// Check is multiple or single line document
            if (IsMultipleLine(input_text))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Is a multiple line file");

                MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input_text, "^(.+)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);

                int line = 0;

                foreach (Match match in matches)
                {
                    foreach (Capture capture in match.Captures)
                    {
                        line++;

                        Console.WriteLine($"Line: {line}");

                        RegexpLine(capture.Value, invalid_character);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Is a single line file");

                RegexpLine(input_text, invalid_character);
            }

            Pause();
        }

        public static bool IsMultipleLine(string input) => regex.IsMatch(input);

        public static void RegexpLine(string line, string characters)
        {
            regex = new Regex(characters);

            MatchCollection mc = regex.Matches(line);

            Console.WriteLine($"How many matches: {mc.Count}");

            foreach (Match match in mc)
                Console.WriteLine($"Index: {match.Index}");
        }

        public static ConsoleKeyInfo Pause(string message = "please press ANY key to continue...")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);

            return Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Thx guys for help, basically will be nice if someone smarter then me, check this code in terms of performance.

Regards,
Nerus.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be split the string into array of string, each contains a line. If the length of the array is just 1, that means you have only 1 line. Then from there you use the Regex to match each line to find the invalid character that you are looking for.

```
string input_text = "Some Înput text here,\nÎs another lÎne of thÎs text.";
string line_pattern = "\n";

// split the string into string arrays
string[] input_texts = input_text.Split(new string[] { line_pattern }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string invalid_character = "Î";

if (input_texts != null && input_texts.Length > 0)
{
    if (input_texts.Length == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Is a single line file");
    }

    // loop every line
    foreach (string oneline in input_texts)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(invalid_character);

        MatchCollection mc = regex.Matches(oneline);

        Console.WriteLine("How many matches: {0}", mc.Count);

        foreach (Match match in mc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}", match.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

--- EDIT ---

Things to consider:

- If you get your input from a file, I would recommend you to read line by line, not the whole text.
- Usually, when you search for invalid character, you don't specify it. Instead you look for a pattern. For ex: Not a char from a-z, A-Z, 0-9. Then your regex is going to be a little bit different.